# How to properly escape the need for sudo needing a password in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, osx, sudo, motd

## Issue

I'm trying to have a dynamic MOTD (message of the day, /etc/motd) and in order to edit the file I need to run sudo. Further, I'm having /etc/profile call a python script that writes to /etc/motd.

In /etc/profile I call `sudo python generateMOTD.py`
In generateMOTD.py I open, write, close.

When a new tab or Terminal is opened, the MOTD displays (the old one, prior to changing) and then I am prompted for a password. I want to not need a password here.

## My attempt at fixing it

To try and fix this I edited /etc/sudoers to include both:

```
<user> ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/etc/generateMOTD.py
<user> ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/etc/profile
```

where `<user>` is my username.

This now works if I call either /etc/profile or /etc/generateMOTD.py from the command line; it doesn't ask for a password.

When I run it as intended (at the start of a session), however, it asks for a password. I added echo/print statements to most of the steps before/after (i.e. before and after calling generateMOTD.py in profile, and before and after my code in generateMOTD.py). So in total there's 4 statements logged to the console that go `profileBefore > pythonCodeBefore > pythonCodeAfter > profileAfter`. When run at the start of a session (new tab/terminal), I am asked for a password just after the first message (profileBefore) but before the rest of the messages. So it has to do with my `sudo python generateMOTD.py` statement but I just can't figure it out.

## All of the files I am dealing with:

*/etc/sudoers:*

```
...
<user> ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/etc/generateMOTD.py

<user> ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/etc/profile
```

*/etc/profile*

```
...
echo "BEFORE PROFILE PYTHON CALL:"
sudo python /etc/generateMOTD.py
echo "AFTER PROFILE PYTHON CALL:"
```

*/etc/generateMOTD.py*

```
print ("IN THE MIDDLE OF THE PYTHON CALL, BEFORE!")
f= open("/etc/motd","w+") 
f.write("!MOTD!\n")
f.close()
print ("IN THE MIDDLE OF THE PYTHON CALL, AFTER WRITE!")
```

Comment: I'd suggest doing this through `crontab` or something in the lines instead of including `sudo something` in /etc/profile. If you want to do it your way, try to `chmod +x /etc/generateMOTD.py` and execute it directly (with shebang).

Comment: Is there no `/etc/update-motd.d/` on OSX?

Comment: @Panki no there isn't